# sap.m.Tree Implementation

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I have been trying to implement the sap.m.tree for multilevel hierarchy data, and the attribute names are different.

I have been through the FIORI guidelines https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/tree/ for the same and I understand that is the exact control I need. from the SAPUI5 explored https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Tree/samples
I couldn't get much of help as they have the example over the same data and there are no aggregations.

Can anyone help me with a lead, an example would be highly appreciated.

Json

```
{
"d": {
    "__count": "4",
    "results": [
        {
            "ID": "1234",
            "FID": "00145E9279201EE799E3027FBE864F24",
            "FName" : "Header"
            "Sequence": 0,
            "Values": {
                "results": [
                    {
                        "ID": "321",
                        "Value": "FChild",
                    },
                     {
                        "ID": "321",
                        "Value": "FChild",
                    }
                ]}
                }]
                }
                }
```

Comment: Can you please show an example, how your input data looks like? 
Can you please give an example, how your tree should look like with different attribute names and aggregations?

Comment: Yes that right, for example the explored app gives me the code to iterate through a JSON file which would have different attribute names.

Comment: Update the question with the JSON

Comment: In your JSON-example you have 2 nodes with same ID “321” and same Value “FChild”.
Do you want these 2 nodes to be displayed as 2 separate nodes or combined into 1 single node?
Should ID “1234” be the root node?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is late but maybe it helps someone else.
The structure of the json for the tree should be like [this](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Tree/sample/sap.m.sample.TreeSelection/code/Tree.json):

```
[
    {
        "text": "Node1",
        "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-audio",
        "nodes":
        [
            {
                "text": "Node1-1",
                "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-e-pub",
                "nodes":[
                    {
                        "text": "Node1-1-1",
                        "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-html"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Node1-1-2",
                        "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-photo",
                        "nodes":[
                            {
                                "text": "Node1-1-2-1",
                                "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-text-file",
                                "nodes":[
                                    {
                                        "text": "Node1-1-2-1-1",
                                        "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-video"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "text": "Node1-1-2-1-2",
                                        "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-zip-file"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "text": "Node1-1-2-1-3",
                                        "ref": "sap-icon://course-program"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "text": "Node1-2",
                "ref": "sap-icon://create"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "text": "Node2",
        "ref": "sap-icon://customer-financial-fact-sheet"
    }
]
```

Then you use it in the "items" aggregation of the Tree. Just format the JSON that way and it will work. The important part is the:

```
[
    {
        "anyTextFieldYouWant": "Node1",
        "nodes":
        [
            {
            "anyTextFieldYouWant": "Node1-1"
            },
            {
            "anyTextFieldYouWant": "Node1-2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```